# Make a dataframe from a call

Tags: r, analysis, geo

I try to use the rgbif api to download biodiversity data for a specific country with this code country

I try this

```
library(rgbif)
dfexample <- dataset_search(country="US", limit = 30)
```

Is it possible to make as a dataframe?

Comment: That doesn't look executable in R.

Comment: @IRTFM i made the update

Comment: You get a list with 4 named elements, each of which is a sublist of varying lengths. You need to describe what you want to be arranged in a rectangular fashion from something that is not currently rectangular .

Comment: @IRTFM using the 4 elements and their sublist as every column in the fashio form like elementname.sublistname to be each one a column. Example for the element data have column like data.datasetTitle, data.datasetKey etc.

Comment: If my answer is not what you intended then you will need to [edit] you question to include a a better description. Don't use comments to amend questions. ( do not see anything with the names 'data.datasetTitle', 'data.datasetKey'

Answer (score 0):

As it currently stands the question is unclear.

```
> names(dfexample)
#[1] "meta"         "data"         "facets"       "descriptions"

sapply(dfexample,class)
$meta
#-----
[1] "data.frame"

$data
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

$facets
[1] "NULL"

$descriptions
[1] "list"

sapply(dfexample, length)
#------
        meta         data       facets descriptions 
           4            8            0           30
```

If you want the data elements to be a dataframe then its already a tibble so just extract it:

```
  dfexample$data    # might be what you wanted
```

You can use str to see the column names in the tbl_df. It should behave like a dataframe for ordinary R functions:

```
str(dfexample$data)
tibble [30 × 8] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ datasetTitle             : chr [1:30] "EOD – eBird Observation Dataset" "GBIF Backbone Taxonomy" "Catalogue of Life - June 2021" "NCBI Taxonomy" ...
 $ datasetKey               : chr [1:30] "4fa7b334-ce0d-4e88-aaae-2e0c138d049e" "d7dddbf4-2cf0-4f39-9b2a-bb099caae36c" "7ddf754f-d193-4cc9-b351-99906754a03b" "fab88965-e69d-4491-a04d-e3198b626e52" ...
 $ type                     : chr [1:30] "OCCURRENCE" "CHECKLIST" "CHECKLIST" "CHECKLIST" ...
 $ hostingOrganization      : chr [1:30] "Cornell Lab of Ornithology" "GBIF Secretariat" "The Catalogue of Life Partnership" "GBIF Secretariat" ...
 $ hostingOrganizationKey   : chr [1:30] "e2e717bf-551a-4917-bdc9-4fa0f342c530" "fbca90e3-8aed-48b1-84e3-369afbd000ce" "f4ce3c03-7b38-445e-86e6-5f6b04b649d4" "fbca90e3-8aed-48b1-84e3-369afbd000ce" ...
 $ publishingOrganization   : chr [1:30] "Cornell Lab of Ornithology" "GBIF Secretariat" "The Catalogue of Life Partnership" "National Center for Biotechnology Information (NCBI)" ...
 $ publishingOrganizationKey: chr [1:30] "e2e717bf-551a-4917-bdc9-4fa0f342c530" "fbca90e3-8aed-48b1-84e3-369afbd000ce" "f4ce3c03-7b38-445e-86e6-5f6b04b649d4" "2f2e4f28-d929-4609-937b-9a8ebd265159" ...
 $ publishingCountry        : chr [1:30] "US" NA NA "US" ..
```

Comment: from the 4 elements two of them contain data the data and description. Using this option it is possible to receive the dataframe for data `dfdescriptions <- as.data.frame(dfexample$descriptions)` how is it possibe to and a column in this dataset with the description?

Comment: If you want an additional column  from a vector of the same length as the number of rows in a dataframe, then just assign it with the `$<-` function: `res <- dfexample$data; res$description <- dfexample$description`